# Mat-tab-body-wrapper, cannot edit css (angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I can't change the mat tab body wrapper which seems to be limiting the size of my mat-tab.

ex.

```
.mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  height: 100%:
}
```

Sorry, Stackoverflow is is forcing me to comment out some unnecessary stuff as you can see with NG-template and my bar chart.

```
  <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs>
     <mat-tab>
        'angular template and mat tab label'
              'extraneous elements'
        'end angular template and mat table label'
        <div class="container">
           'extraneous elements'
              <div style="display: block">
                 <canvas> 
                   /*My Bar chart*/
                 </canvas>
              </div>
        </div>               
     </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

EDIT:

You can actually override elements like this (i.e. mat-tab of angular material) using 
::ng-deep

Comment: What is the behavior you are expecting? the `mat-tab` will usually take the space needed to show your full content unless you specify otherwise

Comment: In which css file you are adding your styles?

Comment: I can't override mat-tab-body-wrapper which seems to have a height and width of "fit-content"  css file is in the .css file of this component in angular

Answer (score 12):

It's because of the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation). By default, Angular scope the styles, so if you write in your `my-component.component.css` the following

```
mat-tab-body-wrapper {
   height: 100%;
}
```

then the `css` is compiled to something like

```
[_nghost-c15] mat-tab-body-wrapper[_ngcontent-c15] { 
   height: 100%;
}
```

and therefore the style is not applied, because the selector don't match.

To solve your problem, just copy your `css` in the global stylesheet (i.e. `styles.css`), but be careful, this action will affect all your bodies from material tabs.

Answer (score 9):

That fixes the issue:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Did this work for anyone? Adding `:host ::ng-deep` didn't make a change for me...

Comment: So, `:host ::ng-deep` didn't work for me, but adding just `::ng-deep` did. So, in full I was able to use: `::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-wrapper `.

Comment: `::ng-deep .mat-tab-body-wrapper` worked for me too.  I like this method a lot better than adjusting the global stylesheet because this way I'm not changing the styles from other areas of my app.

Answer (score 8):

Here is s simple way to fix your problem. Apply a custom css to the  element.

```
<mat-tab-group class="custom-tabs"></mat-tab-group>
```

Import ViewEncapsulation in '@angular/core'

```
import { Component,ViewEncapsulation  } from '@angular/core';
```

Disable view encapsulation in the component which displays the tabs.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

You can now style both .mat-tab-body and .mat-tab-body-wrapper.

```
.custom-tabs .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I highly recommend not setting `ViewEncapsulation` to `none` unless absolutely necessary or you know exactly what you're doing. **A style defined in your global stylesheet is sufficient.** `ViewEncapsulation.None` makes any styles defined in that component global. This can lead to a number of hard to debug issues.

Comment: @DaneBrouwer I know very well but do you have any other way to fix this problem.

Comment: "**A style defined in your global stylesheet is sufficient.**"